# Sum-String coding algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve the first question from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nutanix-interview-experience-set-1-on-campus-for-internship/. In this question, we're given a string of decimal digits, and we have to figure out if there's some way to split it up into four or more substrings ["*A*", "*B*", "*C*", …] such that *A* + *B* = *C*, *B* + *C* = *D*, etc.

For example, if the string is `"12358"`, then the answer is `true`, because we can split it up into ["1", "2", "3", "5", "8"], where 1 + 2 = 3, 2 + 3 = 5, and 3 + 5 = 8.

Similarly, if the string is `"199100199"`, then the answer is `true`, because we can split it up into ["1", "99", "100", "199"], where 1 + 99 = 100 and 99 + 100 = 199.

However, if the string is `"2368"`, then the answer is `false`, because there's only way to break it up into four or more substrings — namely ["2", "3", "6", "8"] — and 3 + 6 ≠ 8.

I can probably think of a solution using two or three nested loops, but I assume I need a more efficient solution?

Comment: What is your nested solution? Start with something that works and then move on to optimising it.

Comment: I don't get the definition, what is `i`, `x` and `j`? Could you explain **sum-string** more detailed please? Or give me some intuition what it means? For example I don't get the second explanation. Why do you add `1` with `99`, I would have guessed that `1 + 9 = 10` is the first computation like in the first example.

Comment: @Zabuza, this is all I have, I can share the original geeks for geeks link from where I found this question. I wish I had more info.
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nutanix-interview-experience-set-1-on-campus-for-internship/

Comment: Are the values for `i`, `x` and `j` possibly *user inputs*? So something like `boolean isSumString(String input, int i, int x, int j)`? It sounds like you only need one loop traversing the input from left to right.

Comment: No i, x, j don't seem to be user input. We have to determine i, x, j.

Comment: Sorry but before we can think of possible implementations we must first understand the definition, you included. The link you provided does not seem to give an answer to that. Especially I don't get why the second works compared to the first. Is the method supposed to find a combination of `i, x, j, l` such that it works in order to prove the existence, is that the definition of a **sum-string**?

Comment: Why are u so confused. The problem states find such triplet if possible. if i,x,j, l are provided, the problem is nothing more than a simple boolean check. The whole goal is to find those in an optimized way

Comment: Now it gets more clear. So an input is a **sum-string** if such values exist. Sounds like a nice code challenge. Please go ahead and try it on your own, then call back if you got stuck or have a more specific question like "*it does not work, what have I done wrong*" or "*can you optimize my code*" or something like that. Definitely not a task that can easily be solved and optimized by us in one minute or so, at least **SO** is not the right place for "*can you solve that task for me*".

Comment: @ringø can u tell how?

Comment: You just have to get the two first numbers right, O(n^2). Start with X:1 digit, Y:1 digit (the next one) and see if that matches the whole string using the description (Z = X+Y etc...). If that doesn't work, use Y with 2 digits etc... until you reach the end, then try X with 2 digits...

Comment: @ringø I am not able to break it down recursively because X has to be a substring from 0-to say idx, and then Y should go from that point till the end and this must repeat in a recursive fashion. Not able to represent it on paper. Any more clues?

Comment: @ringø, I posted a solution. Let me know what you think

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean test3(String s, String d1, String d2, int idx1, int idx2) {
    if(idx1>=s.length()) return false;
    if(idx2>=s.length()) {
        d1 = s.substring(0,idx1);
        return test3(s,d1,d2,idx1+1,1);
    }
    if(!d1.isEmpty() && d1.length()+idx2<=s.length()) {
        d2 = s.substring(d1.length(),d1.length()+idx2);
        int sum = Integer.parseInt(d1) + Integer.parseInt(d2);
        String sumStr = Integer.toString(sum);
        if(s.substring(d1.length()+d2.length()).startsWith(sumStr)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return test3(s,d1,d2,idx1,idx2+1);
        }
    } else {
        d1 = s.substring(0,idx1);
        return test3(s,d1,d2,idx1+1,idx2);

    }
}
```

I tried the above and it seems to work. This is my solution